# Create and insert ID in another table using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I trying to attach a file upload to a currently excisting document in my database.

Got these 2 tables.

**TblFile**
-FileId
-FileName
-FileUrl

**tblFileDoc**
-FileId
-DocId

I've tried with this soulution but i get a foreign key error. So i doubt my code is correct.

```
 var db = new MyModelContext();

    tblFile f = new tblFile();
    f.FileName = txtHead.Text;
    f.FileUrl = TextBox1.Text;
    db.tblFiles.InsertOnSubmit(f);

    FileDoc fd = new FileDoc();
    fd.DocId = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
    f.FileDocs.Add(fd);
    db.FileDocs.InsertOnSubmit(fd);
    db.SubmitChanges();
```

The textboxes are just used as tests..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ia giving you error necause it can not find its foreign key object so what you can do here is Asign your "f" object to fd's tblfile property...
It will solve your problem.

Comment: I am not near to my laptop but I can tell you what needs to be done here just before _f.FileDocs.Add(fd);_ line add code _fd.tblFile = f;_.
I am not sure about the _tblFile_ property in fd object but you'll get this in intellisense.
try this if not work then I'll give you code example when i can.

Comment: Is it possible to post your solution?

Comment: Hey I have tried the example(LINQ2SQL) and i didn't found any problem. data is properly inserted. may be for code you'll need to set the property of 
`fd.FileId = f.FileId `

Comment: My Code -
`var context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
TblFile f = new TblFile()
{
   FileId = 2,
   FileName = "DemoFile",
   FileUrl = "http://www.google.com"
};
context.TblFiles.InsertOnSubmit(f);
var fd = new tblFileDoc()
{
   DocID = 2,
   FileId = 2
};
context.tblFileDocs.InsertOnSubmit(fd);
context.SubmitChanges();`

Comment: Hi again.. Maybe forgot to mention that all ID's are autogeneretet from the MSSQL database. I will populate a dropdownlist with the DocID. But what i dont understand is how i get only the created FileID in the tblFileDoc table